# Best File Location to put a file that I need to read and write to on linux

Tags: java, linux, terminal, fedora, javac

In my code, I read and write to a file called "Global Bookings ID.txt".

And when I run the code in a Windows environment on Netbeans IDE, it works just fine.

```
BufferedReader GBIread = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                new File("resources\\GlobalBookingID.txt")));
```

Here "resources" is parallel to the src folder as seen:

[image: screenshot from windows]

But keeping the code and file path the same in Linux:

[image: screenshot from linux]

The code can not find the file. Below is how I compile and run the code

```
[cst2550@localhost src] javac cst2550CW/GymServer.java
[cst2550@localhost src] java cst2550CW/GymServer
```

Also it did occur to me to change the file path from "resources\GlobalBookingID.txt" to "resources/GlobalBookingID.txt" to account for the different way Linux handles files. but it still does not work.

What's going wrong?

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")`; as the saying goes *there's no place like home*. And that works everywhere.

Comment: oh, my bad, I'm new here and in a bit of a panic. it won't happen again!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you elaborate please?

Comment: I don't see why this would be a compiler related question? Tag `javac` looks misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to avoid when writing portable software is `\\` as a separator in file paths. Use `java.io.File.separatorChar` instead.